# Can tortoise cvs individually work without cvsnt?

Tags: version-control, cvs, tortoisecvs, cvsnt

I want to create a local repository using tortoise tortoise cvs without making a server...
Is it possible??

Comment: I think first you have to create a repository on server then you can create same on your local with out server...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local repository on your computer. You create an empty directory, and call `cvs init` within there (I guess ther is a cvs.exe or cvsnt.exe lying around somewhere in the installation directory of TortoiseCVS. If not you need to get it). Then you can import any local folder into this repository. You enter the file path of the top folder when you are asked for the CVSROOT.

```
:: create the repository
c:
mkdir c:\repo
cvs -dc:\repo init

:: import something
mkdir initial
cd initial
echo 23>42
cvs -dc:\repo import first-module useless-tag-1 useless-tag-2
```

There might be issues with the '\' chars in the path names, you can then try with forward slashes.

But honestly, today I use Mercurial and [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) for version control, which has lots more features and is less painful.

Comment: Why are you doing `svn init` when the question is about cvs?